# Switching to a Remote Repository

Tags: git, github, version-control

[image]

I am trying to switch to the remove repo remotes/origin/image. But if I do `git checkout image` it created a local repo with that name instead. How to switch to the remove repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a repo, it's a branch. And you *don't* switch to it, because the normal git workflow doesn't interact directly with online resources; commit, log, diff, etc. are all *offline* operations. You do `git checkout image` (or more explicitly, `git checkout -t origin/image`) to create a local branch which has the remote branch as its "upstream"; then you can `git push` to send changes to the remote branch, and `git pull` to receive changes. You can keep working even if you're offline.